# How to call a constructor with different arguement in a block where this constructor is defined with a super() call?

Tags: java

I have a situation where i have to do like

```
 class A{

    B b;

    class B extends ContainerView{

    public B(int x,int y, String s1, Styring s2){
    super(x,y,200,500);

    }
    }

    class C{

    void m(){
    if(...){
    B b=new B(x,y,raj,esh);
    b.something....
    else
    B b=new B(x,y,esh,raj);
```

The problem is x and y is unknown to the class C and if i declare it as int x,y in class C then it's behaving improperly....

What to do? Thanks in Advance

Comment: pass null and handle accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

```
class OuterClass {
    ...
    class InnerClass {
        ...
    }
}
```

OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your usage of the class or the class constructor API is wrong.

You gave two options when calling `public B(int x,int y, String s1, String s2)` and `x` and `y` is unknown.

First option is to pass null or or a default value there (since in this case the parameters are int the default can be 0 or something like -1). The class you are creating should be aware that these values may be null or contain an invalid/default value. This is however a patch.

If properly designed and `x` and `y` parameters are optional it should contain a constructor to reflect that `public B(String s1, String s2)`

The second option is to **not** create that particular object there, if `x` and `y` is unknown and those parameters are no optional. You have placed it in the wrong place where critical contextual parameters for object creation is not present.